# Differentiation Of Natural Logarithms

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

The problem I have is  to differentiate $ y = ln(x^4)$

Using the rule :
$$\frac{d[lnf(x)]}{dx}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
My working is:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^4ln(x)}{x^4}$$
$$=ln(x)$$

but the book is giving the answer : 
$$\frac{4}{x}$$

Please help because I am confused

Comment: Caution: $$\log x^4=4\log |x|\neq x^4\log x\;\;!$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = x^4$. Thus $f'(x) = 4x^3$. Plug into provided rule.

Comment: Note that the "rule" is merely an application of the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment and assuming $\,x>0\,$ to avoid the absolute value:

$$y=\log x^4=4\log x\Longrightarrow y'=\frac{4}{x}= $$

Comment: Thank you, another way which makes it easy to work out...